# Sandbox / Testing environment?

Tags: xtrf

Is there a testing environment available to help implement the "Web Service API for Partners 1.0"? Our company is in the late stages of deploying XTRF and would like to help one of our partners get started implementing the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) tool to test any WS API, in particular also XTRF WS API for Partners.

To start testing API in SoapUI you have to create project corresponding to the WS API:

```
File > New soapUI Project
```

Fill WSDL/WADL field with the URL of the API WSDL, in case of Partners API it should look like:

```
http(s)://<your-domain.com>/translationManagementService/PartnerWSAPI?WSDL
```

Remaining fields should be filled automatically, then accept with OK. Now, you should have project with structure of methods (see screen) together with sample requests for each method.

You can test API now, but remember to login as Customer first.

---

Full API documentation is available [here](http://knowledgebase.xtrf.eu/display/XTRFAPIWSP/Home)